# Detecting Parameters HTTP

Tags: javascript

Is there a way, when a page loads or at some point in time, to detect if there are parameters in the URL?

I'm working on a project where I send to and get messages from a server, but in doing so there are uri's which have information in them.

`https:/www.example.com/?code=123&name=me`

and i would like to know when I get them.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `location.search` property, which returns the full value of the querystring.

You'll need to parse it yourself.

Comment: Secretly, I was hoping there was another solution. Currently this does not allow the rest of my communication to occur. I'll see what wrap-arounds can happen.

Comment: @TeloSprings: Huh? Are you asking for server-side code?

Comment: No I am not. When I add `location.search` to my JavaScript file, none of my other script executes.

Comment: @TeloSprings: Use the debugger to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may check if the url contains "?", `if (url.contains('?')) {} else {}`